# Twilio call disconnect reason

Tags: twilio

I am making outbound call from Twilio to mobile number and sometimes it will be a conference call so in live call if any of the reason call get disconnected then my question is twilio send any disconnect reason back so I can track those information and I will again initiate a call if it is abruptly disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a error handler in your call as per the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#error) which says:

> Register a handler function to be called when any device error occurs during the lifetime of this connection. These may be errors in your request, your capability token, connection errors, or other application errors.

Any call disconnect will be caught in this error handler registered and then you can decide what to do with it. It also displays the error code which shows why the call got disconnected/showed error and each error code can be referenced [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors) which tells you what happened to the call.

Comment: How can handle this with java code the documentation which you mention is about javascript or browser phone. I have tried to implement error handling in java but any abruptly call disconnect there is no error.